# my doinbackground method timeouts without retrieving

Tags: json

My android App is not retrieving through json_encode from php script. my android and php code is correct i checked by browser it retrieves. I provided correct url. but it did just time out.  my android studio has internal IDE problem and says NullPointerException:Null after gradle sync. could it be the problem?

Comment: I suggest adding code snippets of what you tried, so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate and restart your Android  studio IDE. We could help you better if you post the code.